# "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0" error when running integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have a project in Java and Spring Boot but every time I try to run any of the integration tests, I keep getting an "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0" error. The application itself is working normally, it's only the integration tests that are not functioning. I started getting this error after transferring the project from macOS to Windows. Before doing this, I wasn't experiencing any issues.

**Stack trace** (not the whole one because it's too long to post):

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.5)

2024-01-03T19:09:50.600+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] c.g.i.i.c.LifeInsControllerTest    : Starting LifeInsControllerTest using Java 21.0.1 with PID 5992 (started by User in C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\project\backend)
2024-01-03T19:09:50.605+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] c.g.i.i.c.LifeInsControllerTest    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-01-03T19:10:15.335+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-01-03T19:10:16.391+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1012 ms. Found 3 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2024-01-03T19:10:21.837+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring.autoconfigure.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration' of type [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring.autoconfigure.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-01-03T19:10:22.609+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded-de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring.autoconfigure.EmbeddedMongoProperties' of type [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring.autoconfigure.EmbeddedMongoProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-01-03T19:10:23.645+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'net' of type [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.ImmutableNet] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-01-03T19:10:23.662+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.data.mongodb-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-01-03T19:10:30.219+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] d.f.e.m.s.a.SyncClientServerFactory      : sync server factory
2024-01-03T19:10:56.759+01:00  WARN 5992 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'allInsController' defined in file [C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\project\backend\target\classes\com\github\userdev\project\controllers\AllInsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'LifeInsService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\project\backend\target\classes\com\github\userdev\project\services\LifeInsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'LifeInsRepo' defined in com.github.userdev.project.repositories.LifeInsRepo defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
2024-01-03T19:10:56.813+01:00  INFO 5992 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-03T19:10:58.678+01:00 ERROR 5992 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'allInsController' defined in file [C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\project\backend\target\classes\com\github\userdev\project\controllers\AllInsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'LifeInsService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\project\backend\target\classes\com\github\userdev\project\services\LifeInsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'LifeInsRepo' defined in com.github.userdev.project.repositories.LifeInsRepo defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    
..............

org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
    
..............

    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'LifeInsService' defined in file [C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\project\backend\target\classes\com\github\userdev\project\services\LifeInsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'LifeInsRepo' defined in com.github.userdev.project.repositories.LifeInsRepo defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 96 common frames omitted

..............

    ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'syncClientServerWrapper' defined in class path resource [de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/spring/autoconfigure/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration$SyncClientServerWrapperConfig.class]: rollback after error on transition to State(de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.transitions.RunningMongodProcess), successful reached:
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.process.archives.ExtractedFileSet}=ExtractedFileSet{baseDir=C:\Users\User\.embedmongo\fileSets\253d3396ba601815ef3174d79e561930c469215dd7fb5ec61f048506fe4fa62a, executable=C:\Users\User\.embedmongo\fileSets\253d3396ba601815ef3174d79e561930c469215dd7fb5ec61f048506fe4fa62a\mongod.exe, libraryFiles=[]},
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.process.types.Archive}=Archive(C:\Users\User\.embedmongo\archives\https-fastdl-mongodb-org\56cb3d10404e5b9df5358ac4ee83efcb\windowsmongodb-windows-x86-64-6-0-1-zip\d4488999d6dcbca066e9af590e9c6810fbfd67008d5d27324c764957ce92a8ef\archive.zip),
  StateID{name=, type=interface de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.DownloadCache}=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.LocalDownloadCache@5c9934da,
  StateID{name=, type=interface de.flapdoodle.embed.process.config.store.Package}=Package{archiveType=ZIP, fileSet=FileSet{entries=[Entry{type=Executable, destination=mongod.exe, uncompiledMatchingPattern=UncompiledPattern{regex=.*mongod.exe, flags=2}}]}, url=https://fastdl.mongodb.org/windows/mongodb-windows-x86_64-6.0.1.zip},
  StateID{name=, type=interface de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ExtractedFileSetStore}=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ContentHashExtractedFileSetStore@4cb702ce,
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.process.types.ProcessArguments}=ProcessArguments([--dbpath, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\temp--0a892505-0d6f-4a05-afea-0edfcc60a592\mongod-database966216220303227015, --noauth, --nojournal, --port, 50980, --bind_ip, 127.0.0.1, --syncdelay=0]),
  StateID{name=, type=class 

..............

  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.process.types.ProcessEnv}=ProcessEnv({}),
  StateID{name=, type=interface de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.ProcessOutput}=ProcessOutput{output=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.Slf4jStreamProcessor@64c781a9, error=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.Slf4jStreamProcessor@71ed560f, commands=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.NamedOutputStreamProcessor@5b88b8e},
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.types.SystemEnv}=SystemEnv({NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK=1, LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local, PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO, USERDOMAIN=User-PC, LOGONSERVER=\\USER-PC, SESSIONNAME=Console, ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\, SystemDrive=C:, OneDrive=C:\Users\User\OneDrive, APPDATA=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming, USERNAME=User, windows_tracing_logfile=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log, ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86), CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files, Path=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\User\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin, PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, OS=Windows_NT, windows_tracing_flags=3, COMPUTERNAME=USER-PC, PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09, CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, ProgramData=C:\ProgramData, ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files, HOMEPATH=\Users\User, SNC_LIB_64=C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SNCEncryption\x64\sapsncencryption.dll, SystemRoot=C:\Windows, TEMP=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp, HOMEDRIVE=C:, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel, SNC_LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SNCEncryption\x86\sapsncencryption.dll, USERPROFILE=C:\Users\User, TMP=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp, CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files, PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2, windir=C:\Windows, =::=::\, IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\User\Desktop, IWBPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\iwb}),
  StateID{name=, type=interface de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.progress.ProgressListener}=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.progress.Slf4jProgressListener@58253c57,
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.packageresolver.Command}=MongoD,
  StateID{name=, type=interface de.flapdoodle.embed.process.distribution.Version}=GenericFeatureAwareVersion{6.0.1},
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.Net}=Net{bindIp=127.0.0.1, port=50980, isIpv6=false},
  StateID{name=, type=class de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.commands.MongodArguments}=MongodArguments{syncDelay=0, useDefaultSyncDelay=false, isVerbose=false, verbosityLevel=1, isQuiet=false, useNoPrealloc=true, useSmallFiles=true, useNoJournal=true, enableTextSearch=false, auth=false, master=false, isConfigServer=false, isShardServer=false, params={}, args={}}

..............

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 124 common frames omitted

..............

============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    None


Negative matches:
-----------------

    None


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None

Process finished with exit code -1
```

**AllInsController:**

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/getall")
public class AllInsController {
    private LifeInsService lifeInsService;
    private PropertyInsService propertyInsService;
    private VehicleInsService vehicleInsService;

    @GetMapping
    public AllInsResponse getAllIns() {
        List<LifeIns> lifeIns = lifeInsService.getAllLifeIns();
        List<PropertyIns> propertyInss = propertyInsService.getAllPropertyIns();
        List<VehicleIns> vehicleIns = vehicleInsService.getAllVehicleIns();

        return new AllInsResponse(lifeIns, propertyIns, vehicleIns);
    }
}
```

**LifeInsService:**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LifeinsService {
    private LifeInsRepo lifeInsRepo;

    public List<LifeIns> getAllLifeIns () {
        return lifeInsRepo.findAll();
    }

    public LifeIns getLifeInsById(String id) {
        return lifeInsRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(NoSuchInsException::new);
    }

    public LifeIns addLifeIns (LifeIns lifeIns) {
        return lifeInsRepo.save(lifeIns);
    }

    public void deleteLifeIns (String id) {
        lifeInsRepo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**LifeInsRepo:**

```
@Repository
public interface LifeInsRepo extends MongoRepository <LifeIns, String> {

}
```

**One of my integration tests** (I get the same error for all of them):

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class LifeInsControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired
    private LifeInsRepo lifeInsRepo;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "/api/life";

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    void getAllLifeIns() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URI))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("[]"));
    }
}
```

**application.properties** for the tests:

```
de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded.version=6.0.1
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.github.userdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <sonar.organization>userdev</sonar.organization>
        <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-   base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Why aren't my integration tests working and how do I fix the problem? I will provide additional inforamtion if necessary. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems the mongo db is not initialized, scroll and read the stack trace. 

  ````Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
````        

Maybe the IP or port of Mongo db has changed? What do you have in your parameters file? can you connect to MongoDb from where your code is running using those same IP, user etc?

Comment: Which parameters file do you mean? I'm using MongoDB Atlas and I can connect to its database from my current system and see all records. Despite that, none of my integration tests is working.

Comment: Can you share you application properties file that you have declared for testing ?

Comment: I already posted it, that's what it contains:
`de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded.version=6.0.1`
I'm using Flapdoodle for my tests and didn't change anything in it after transferring the project.

Comment: after seeing @mohamed-mamun answer seems you are not having the same version? maybe start a fresh project on windows and make a basic 1 method to test repo, service and controller project? then copy copde from existing to new one, a class at a time?

Comment: which ide are you usig? are u able to do a mvn compile from commandline? or skip tests and do     ````    mvn install -DskipTests    ```` If your using intelli J restart the IDE after clearing ccaches (one of the menus in the File menu) and then rebuild, are there any errors? https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring  has <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring3x</artifactId> you have spring30x<

Comment: Do you mean to copy the whole project code to a new project? Yes, I'm using IntelliJ. In the terminal in IntelliJ, I keep getting `The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`. I'm not getting any errors when clearing the caches and rebuilding the projects. If I write `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring3x` I'm getting an error.

Comment: I should also add that I transferred my project by cloning my GitHub repository if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

after reading your codes, I have found some errors.

Try the next solutions, I hope it solve your problem.

In `AllInsController`you're using `LifeInsService` dependency, but you never injected the dependency into the current class. To do that, add `@Autowired`annotation above the dependency (LifeInService).

In `LifeInsService`you have to repeat the same process for `LifeInsRepo`.

In `LifeInsRepo` you have to add one more annotation to deal with MongoReposotory. Add `@EnableMongoRepositories` after `@Repository`annotation.

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/getall")
public class AllInsController {

    @Autowired
    private LifeInsService lifeInsService;
    ....
}
```

//Service

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LifeinsService {
@Autowired
private LifeInsRepo lifeInsRepo;
```

//Reposotory

```
@Repository
@EnableMongoRepositories
public interface LifeInsRepo extends MongoRepository <LifeIns, String> {

}
```

Comment: I changed my code as you recommended but I still keep getting the same error as before.

Comment: Hi @fins44, take a look in this post https://medium.com/@prekshaan95/difference-between-spring-boot-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository-6da468bd716a

Comment: I made my tests working by using an actual MongoDB database instead of Flapdoodle. Is not perfect but enough for me to achieve what I currently need.